# Сохранить изображение большого грфика winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, изображения, диаграммы

Использую winForms для построения графиков. Метод для сохранения изображения :

```
VolChart.SaveImage("chart.jpeg", ChartImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

Поначалу этого хватало, но когда графики выросли до >700 XPoints изображения стали совершенно не информативны. Есть ли способ сохранить изображение в `jpeg` так что бы разрешение было достаточно большим, например `(200x5000)` а график достаточно разборчивым ? Есть ли способ сразу нарисовать график не используя `Chart` и не визуализируя его на форме ?

Comment: zedgraph пробовали?

Comment: @VladimirT не пробовал. стандартными средствами не обойтись ?

Comment: обойтись можно, вопрос только сколько у вас есть времени на обход ошибок, замечу, что некоторые сторонние средства очень хороши, и имеют кучу документации, ну и соответственно множество раз освещались на форумах и блогах.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как уже выше заметили, лучше найти замену стандартному Chart. Помимо упомянутого zedgraph рекомендую обратить внимание на:

- [OxyPlot](http://www.oxyplot.org/)
- [LiveCharts](https://lvcharts.net/)

Comment: Эти библиотеки умеют сохранять графики с высоким разрешением ? что бы потом можно было распечатать и нормально читать.

Comment: Первая точно умеет

Comment: Хорошая библиотека OxyPlot. спасибо за подсказку.

Answer (score 1):

OxyPlot действительно оказался отличной библиотекой и идеально подошел для меня.

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    var _fileData = new DataSource();
    var volumeModel = new PlotModel { Title = "Volume Chart" };
    var volume = new ColumnSeries
    {
        FillColor = OxyColor.FromRgb(255, 95, 95)
    };
    for (var i=0;  i< _fileData.DataItems.Length; i++)
    {
        var item = _fileData.DataItems[i];
        volume.Items.Add(new ColumnItem { Value = item.value });
    }
    volumeModel.Series.Add(volume);
    this.volumePlot.Model = volumeModel;

    using (var stream = File.Create("Volume.pdf"))
    {
        var pdfExporter = new PdfExporter { Width = 13000, Height = 400 };
        pdfExporter.Export(volumeModel, stream);
    }

}
```